# What is the difference between duckduckgo.com and start.duckduckgo.com?

Tags: domain, search-engine, duckduckgo

Both https://duckduckgo.com and https://start.duckduckgo.com present as the first page of the search engine. I configure my browser to pass search queries to either of them.

I learnt about the `start.` domain when I stepped through a tutorial/infobox on the regular domain that suggested something like "never see this again".

What is the difference if I use one domain rather than the other? (I'd prefer official documentation that clarifies the goal rather than (just) the implementation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The redirect from the regular start page states:

> Clear your cookies often? Try our homepage that never shows these messages: start.duckduckgo.com

...this implies that the regular homepage sets a cookie to hide messages the next time you visit, while the "start" page just never displays them.

According to an [official DDG support representative on the DDG forum](https://duck.co/forum/thread/24265/block-duckduckgo-install-pop-up-how-to), `start.duckduckgo.com` was introduced in 2016 as a "cleaner start page". You'll notice there are fewer UI elements, such as tips or links to add-ons, at the `start.duckduckgo.com` domain. The search experience is exactly the same, though.